# How do i change the time between 2 reservation in Agreservations?

Tags: 7, hooks

i didn't spoted any field that can change that.
I book meetings rooms that can be booked multiple time in a day (hour reservation).
 But for exemple i have one reservation early morning (8:00 to 9:00), i can't book the same room on late morning (9:30 to 12:00)
it return the error:

> There is a ressource conflict: [room name] is currently booked for [previous reservation name] from [date] 8:00 to [date] 9:00. Please choose a different time or a different ressources.

I can book the same day but 2 hours after the end of the previous reservation.

How can i change that setting? if i can't can i change the code?